# How to count, add and find the average of three columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to count the elements of three columns, add them and draw the average with the number of trains in a point or location.

Example table

```
  Localizaton  | Numbers_trains|  Engine_1 |  Engine_2| Engine_3
    A          |  4            |    2      |   4      |  4
    A          |  12           |    3      |   1      |  8
    B          |  43           |    2      |   3      |  9
    B          |  45           |    3      |   5      |  3 
    B          |  23           |    5      |   6      |  2
    C          |  54           |    7      |   8      |  3
```

**My idea is to do something like:**

```
Value_1 AS E1,
Value_2 AS E2,
Value_3 AS EC3
sum (count (E1) + count (E2) + count (E3) ) AS TOTAL
AVG (TOTAL/ Numbers_trains) AS Average
```

**The result is to obtain:**

```
  Localizaton  |    AVG        |
    A          |  4            |    
    A          |  13           |    
    B          |  4,5          |    
    B          |  10           |  
    B          |  2,5          |   
    C          |  5,4          |
```

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: what result do you expect for this data?

Comment: Do you need only Average (TOTAL/ Numbers_trains) as final result  or you need  individual counts also?

Comment: I have updated an example result

Comment: OK @Macgregor updated my answer - I think that's what you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Note: I haven't included a `GROUP BY` statement as the `SELECT` contains only group functions (e.g. `SUM` and `COUNT`)

```
SELECT SUM(engine_1) AS sum_e1
     , SUM(engine_2) AS sum_e2
     , SUM(engine_3) AS sum_e3
     , (SUM(engine_1) + SUM(engine_2) + sum(engine_3)) AS sum_e_total
     , COUNT(*) AS count_total
     , (SUM(engine_1) + SUM(engine_2) + sum(engine_3)) / COUNT(*) AS avg_e
  FROM [table_name]
```

**Edit**

Following your edit - think this should work:

```
SELECT Localization
     , SUM(Number_trains) AS sum_num_trains
     , SUM(Engine_1) AS sum_e1
     , SUM(Engine_2) AS sum_e2
     , SUM(Engine_3) AS sum_e3
     , (SUM(Engine_1) + SUM(Engine_2) + SUM(Engine_3)) AS sum_e_total
     , COUNT(*) AS count_total
     , (SUM(Engine_1) + SUM(Engine_2) + SUM(Engine_3)) / COUNT(*) AS avg_e
  FROM [table_name]
 GROUP BY Localization
 ORDER BY Localization ASC
```

**Edit 2**

Getting `COUNT([Engine_])`

```
SELECT Localization
     , SUM(Number_trains) AS sum_num_trains
     , SUM(Engine_1) AS sum_e1
     , COUNT(Engine_1) AS count_e1
     , SUM(Engine_2) AS sum_e2
     , COUNT(Engine_2) AS count_e2
     , SUM(Engine_3) AS sum_e3
     , COUNT(Engine_3) AS count_e3
     , (SUM(Engine_1) + SUM(Engine_2) + SUM(Engine_3)) AS sum_e_total
     , COUNT(*) AS count_total
     , (SUM(Engine_1) + SUM(Engine_2) + sum(Engine_3)) / COUNT(*) AS avg_e
  FROM [table_name]
 GROUP BY Localization
 ORDER BY Localization ASC
```

---

Note: You don't *need* to pull out the `sum_e1`, `sum_e2` etc - I've just added them for demonstration purposes.

Check out this article about `GROUP` functions:

http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-functions.htm

**Edit 3**

Getting the result you want! *Hopefully*...

Average engines *by* localization and number of trains.

```
SELECT Localization
     , Number_trains
     , (SUM(Engine_1) + SUM(Engine_2) + SUM(Engine_3)) / COUNT(*) AS avg_e
  FROM [table_name]
 GROUP BY Localization
     , Number_trains
 ORDER BY Localization ASC
     , Number_trains ASC
```

Comment: What I must do is first count the engines, add them.

Comment: Should be able to do it with `COUNT` - let me update the answer.

Comment: `COUNT` should work here, as it's a `GROUP` function. Check out this article here: http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-functions.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers and the time dedicated.

In my real query SQL, in the tables Engines have rows, which can be numbers or letters, so I need to count them, so if you do Sum (engine1) it jumps an error of invid number.

Comment: I've tried this and it seems to work:    (count (engine1) + count(engine2)+ count(engine3)) / count(numberr_trians) as AVG_result

Comment: `COUNT` is different to `SUM` - which might be fine, as I don't know your dataset (and you do!) - but to double check - pop a sample of your raw data into something like Microsoft Excel (or good old-fashioned paper) and see if it matches the desired output.

Sorry I haven't been able to provide a direct answer to your query.